# Trying to get property of non-object error in hosting, but in local is not error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show my product history like this one in my localhost
[image: Screenshot of local host]

but when i tried in hosting ended up with an error like this

[image: Screenshot of hosting]

this is my model code

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';

    public function User(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function Product(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

this is my Controller code

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Transaction;
    use App\Cart;
    use App\Product;
    use Auth;
    class TransactionController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){

          $userTransaction = Transaction::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
          $userTransactiondate = Transaction::select('created_at')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
          $getpayment = Transaction::select('payment')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

          return view('transaction.history',compact('userTransaction','userTransactiondate','getpayment'));
        }
    }
```

this is the view code that error

```
                @foreach ($userTransaction as $u)

                  <tr>
                  <td ><img src="{{public_path('productImg/' . $u->Product->product_image)}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""></td>
                  <td><br>{{$u->Product->product_name}}</td>
                  <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{$u->Qty}}</td>
                  <td> <br>X</td> 
                  <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{$u->Product->Price}}</td>
                  <td><br>=</td>
                  <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{$u->Total_Price}}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

how am i supposed to do with this error? the code is same in localhost and in hosting, thank you

Comment: Where is the Product in $u coming from?

Comment: Product is the model, i try to get the product_image,product_name,and price from there

Comment: I understand that it's the model. But I don't see you loading that model. I only see you loading data from the `Transaction` model. Could you show the `Transaction` model?

Comment: Or just show the relation to Product on that model

Comment: i already upload the transaction model above

Comment: It seems you Product relation on that Transaction is null. Are you sure it exists on each row? You could add a row after your foreach like: `@if(!is_null($u->Product))` .... @endif

Comment: its null i already tried, but why my product history work in my local but null in hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of php version and error reporting config may different in your local server and hosting server. You should check `Product` object is exist or not every time. Try this way, maybe helpful for you.

```
@foreach ($userTransaction as $u)
    <tr>
    <td ><img src="{{public_path('productImg/' . optional($u->Product)->product_image)}}" width="100" height="100" alt=""></td>
    <td><br>{{optional($u->Product)->product_name}}</td>
    <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{$u->Qty}}</td>
    <td> <br>X</td> 
    <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{optional($u->Product)->Price}}</td>
    <td><br>=</td>
    <td style="padding-top:30px;">{{$u->Total_Price}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: its show error like this **Call to undefined function optional()**

Comment: which laravel version you are using? please check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional for detail